# How to dispose XMLDocument object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sharepoint

I am trying to dispose the memory from an XmlDocument object

```
using (XmlNodeReader xnrAwards = new XmlNodeReader(ndListItems))
{
    ndListItems.InnerXml = ndListItems.InnerXml.Replace("_x002e_", "_").Replace("ows_", "");
    dsAward.ReadXml(xnrAwards, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
    XmlDocument xdocAwards = new XmlDocument();
    xdocAwards.LoadXml(ndListItems.OuterXml);
    xdocAwards.Save(ABCListName + "_XML.xml");
}
```

Any idea on how to dispose the memory off this object as this is giving me an outofmemoryexception

Comment: how big is your xml file?

Comment: Hi, I have 136 XML files varying from 5MB to 18 MB

Comment: What else is taking up memory in your app?

Comment: It is mainly these XML elements; XmlDocument, XmlNode

Comment: Mind you this is inside a For Loop. Will it make a difference if I declare the XmlDocument xdocAwards = new XmlDocument();
outside the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using `XmlDocument` if memory is a concern. It loads the entire document at once, which is causing you your issues.

Use instead a stream-based reader: `XmlReader`

This object chunks up the file into a buffer instead of loading the entire thing.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file)) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        //Do processing on each 
    }
 }
```

Note this is a forward-only reader, and it's not as straight-forward to use as `XmlDocument`, but buffering your data will ensure you don't run into further memory exceptions.

If you're curious about the mechanism used for buffering, it's a `yield return` behind the scenes (which is actually compiled to a `switch case` if you want to get down to the nitty-gritty). Here is a blog post of someone doing something similar with a text file: http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/processing-a-text-file-with-the-c-yield-return-pattern/

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader